# Spring-data-jpa projection generating query incorrectly

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I've made a sample project that uses spring-data-jpa projection feature, but it's generating incorrect query. Instead of fetching declared field only it's fetching the whole entity. Here is the link for sample project:

https://github.com/ravshansbox/spring-data-jpa-projection-demo

Can anyone explain the reason?

Comment: did you try on the customer repository @Query("your query", nativeQuery = true)

Comment: why to write custom query? why native one?

Comment: its just approach , not a answer , same example here look at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/commit/e253f0e951315a5599b769616db41bf4416a0ce3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it was the version. Upgrading spring-boot to 1.4.0.RELEASE solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem and I am already using spring-boot 1.5.1.RELEASE.
Are you sure updating spring-boot to 1.4.0.RELEASE fixed your issue and not something different?

My interface:

```
public interface CommentWithoutData {

public Long getId();

public String getUsername();
```

}

Generated (SQL) query: select comment0_.id as id1_0_, comment0_.created as created2_0_, comment0_.data as data3_0_, comment0_.username as username4_0_ from comment comment0_

Regards

Comment: yes, I'm sure, with 1.4.0.RELEASE it works as expected.

Comment: I tested it with 1.5.1.RELEASE also, works corrently.

Comment: Ok thanks. Very strange. I don't know why it is not working in my case. I will try to figure it out. Do you have any ideas looking at my code?

Comment: Yes, please, publish somewhere so I can have access.